# Looping through a date range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with a `datetime` column. I need to test some function by increasin the data one day at a time. My `datetime range` goes from the last days of September to the first few days of October. My question is: how do I split the days and "add" more data at each iteration? I'm after something like:

```
for d in range(0927,1010):
  fn(df[df["20100927":d])
```

So at the beginning, it's only one day of data, after the second iteration it will be two days, etc.

Another way to think this: I have

```
 t = pd.date_range(start='20100923', end='20101006')
```

how do I slice `df` like

```
 for d in t:
   df["20100923": d]
```

**EDIT**: I've been able to make it work, but it's not pretty... isn't it possible to just iterate over the `date_range` object? My solution:

```
D = ['2010-09-27', '2019-09-28'] #and so on
for d in D:
  df[df[D[0]:d]
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242692/pandas-increment-datetime) will help you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do. Are you adding on to the DataFrame with new dates? Or are you trying to consider a sub-set of the data that is within a range?

Comment: @tom: I'm trying to consider a subset

Comment: Are the dates in columns or rows? And if they are rows, what's the name of that column?

Comment: There's a `datetime` column, which stores `datetime` objects

Comment: Are there different years we need to contend with? Or can we just say that if the day/month match we're good?

Comment: I think this is resample + reindex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slice pandas dataframe based on datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878699/slice-pandas-dataframe-based-on-datetime-column)

Comment: @jorijnsmit: Thanks. No, what I'm tring to do is keep on adding a larger subset of the data at each iteration, maybe using dateindex.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
start_index = df[df['datetime']=='20100927'].index[0]
days_to_test = 30

for offset in days_to_test:
    fn(df.iloc[start_index:start_index+offset])
```